# How to convert this Formik code into Typescript error free code

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, formik

[image]

I would like to know how to pass the values:

```
onSubmit={(input, { setSubmitting, resetForm })
```

into a function. this is a `formik` code. also i would like to know how to get away with this warning:

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Instead of linking screen shots of your whole editor, could you please copy and paste the relevant code in here. You can easily format code blocks with markdown by using backticks

Comment: Hi Clara thanks for the reply! I will edit this post and place my whole code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Heres my whole code Clara:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ContainerFluid } from 'strapi-helper-plugin';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { StoreVariantDetails } from './StoreVariantDetails';
import { Store } from 'plugins/store-stocks/core/models/store/store';
import { FormikErrors, FormikProps, Formik, Field, Form, FormikHelpers, InjectedFormikProps, withFormik } from 'formik';
import './components-style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const STORES_GQL = gql`
  {
    stores {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;
const CREATE_STORE_GQL = gql`
  mutation createStore($input: createStoreInput!) {
    createStore(input: $input) {
      store {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

const modalStyle = {
  content: {
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    right: 'auto',
    bottom: 'auto',
    marginRight: '-50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
  },
};

const StoreList = () => {
  const { loading, data } = useQuery<{ stores: Store[] }>(STORES_GQL, { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' });
  let content: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] = <></>;
  let formContent: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] = <></>;
  const [createStore] = useMutation(CREATE_STORE_GQL);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const toggleModal = () => {
    setShowModal(!showModal);
  };

  if (loading) {
    content = <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { stores } = data;
    if (!stores?.length) {
      content = <p>No stores declared.</p>;
      formContent = (
        <div>
          <button onClick={toggleModal} className="add-store-button">
            Add New Store
          </button>
          <Modal isOpen={showModal} onRequestClose={toggleModal} style={modalStyle} ariaHideApp={false}>
            <div>{initForm(stores, createStore)}</div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      content = stores.map(store => (
        <React.Fragment key={store.id}>
          <h1 key={store.id}>{store.name}</h1>
        </React.Fragment>
      ));
      formContent = (
        <div>
          <button onClick={toggleModal} className="add-store-button">
            Add New Store
          </button>
          <Modal isOpen={showModal} onRequestClose={toggleModal} style={modalStyle} ariaHideApp={false}>
            <div>{initForm(stores, createStore)}</div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <ContainerFluid>
      <div className="store-stocks-container">
        <div className="store-stocks-stores">{content}</div>
        <div className="store-stocks-add-button">{formContent}</div>
      </div>
    </ContainerFluid>
  );
};

export default StoreList;

const initForm = (stores: Store[], createStore: (data: object) => {}) => {
  interface StoreFormValues {
    storeName: string;
    parentStore: number;
  }
  const initialValues: StoreFormValues = { storeName: '', parentStore: 0 };
  const options = stores.map(store => (
    <option key={store.id} value={store.id}>
      {store.name}
    </option>
  ));
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={(input, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
        setSubmitting(true);
        createStore({ variables: { input: { data: { name: input.storeName, parentStore: input.parentStore } } } });
        alert('Store ' + input.storeName + ' has been added!');
        window.location.reload();
        resetForm();
        setSubmitting(false);
      }}
    >
      {({ values, isSubmitting, handleChange }) => (
        <Form>
          <label className="store-form-label">Name:</label>
          <Field
            placeholder="Store name here..."
            name="storeName"
            type="input"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={values.storeName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="store-form-input"
          />
          <br />
          <label className="store-form-label">ParentStore:</label>
          <Field component="select" name="parentStore" value={values.parentStore} className="store-form-select">
            <option value={0} />
            {options}
          </Field>
          <button disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit" className="store-form-button">
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```